# How to do XSLT 2.0 transform using saxon s9api? XML file to XML file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm new to XML so bear with me. I need to transform an xml file to another xml file. It needs xslt 2.0. I am using saxon's s9api. Using their documentation this what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer;



class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Processor processor = new Processor(false);
        XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        DocumentBuilder builder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
        try {
            builder.build(new File("C:\\XMLFILE.xml"));
        } catch (SaxonApiException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            XsltExecutable xsl = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File("C:\\XSLFILE.xsl")));
            XsltTransformer trans = xsl.load();
            trans.transform();


        } catch (SaxonApiException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is this the right direction? If it is and this is actually performing the transformation how do I specify the output xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a destination on the transformer, for example an output File.

```
Serializer out = new Serializer();
out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "html");
out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
out.setOutputFile(new File("<filelocation>"));
```

Then set on the transformer

```
transformer.setDestination(out);
```

Before you make the call to transform().

```
trans.transform();
```

Comment: I need to transform to xml. Can I just replace "html" with "xml"?

Comment: Also it give me the following error: Either a source document, an initial template or an initial function must be specified. Is that not what I did in the first try block?

Comment: You should also set the initial context node on your transformer.  Your call to builder.build() should return a XdmNode.  Set a local variable with the XdmNode (say source) and then set the initial context on the transformer transformer.setInitialContextNode(source).

Comment: To transform to xml, change the extension on the file your outputting to .xml and yes change the Serializer.Property.METHOD from "html" to "xml"

Comment: The Serializer constructor seems to be protected in 9.8.0 - you have to call the `newSerializer()` method of the `Processor` object to create it.